# Call and online meeting bot - Peer to peer call is terminated automatically

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am trying to develop a simple bot that is supposed to answer incoming call made in personal chat with bot. The bot is employing application hosted media to play or get access to media streams. I am making use of classes and controllers that are implemented in [Huebot sample project at Github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/HueBot). The bot is registered on MS Azure and i am using `ngrok` for local testing and debugging. While debugging after making the call, breakpoints are hit that are placed in '`CallsOnIncoming`' or '`CallsOnUpdated`' event handlers. So my bot configurations over Azure and in MS Teams seem to be correct. For setting up media platform, I have installed the wildcard SSL certificated issued by `Let's Encrypt` and CName records are created for corresponding tcp URLs exposed by ngrok. The environment is multi-tenant i.e. bot registration is done on another tenant, while bot is installed and tested in MS Teams on another tenant.
These are Media platform settings:

```
 MediaPlatformInstanceSettings = new MediaPlatformInstanceSettings()
                    {
                        CertificateThumbprint = "0B687..................",
                        InstanceInternalPort = 8445,
                        InstancePublicPort = 15410,
                        InstancePublicIPAddress = new IPAddress(0x0),
                        ServiceFqdn = "4.mycustomdomain.com",

                    },
```

Here's the snapshot for ngrok:
[image]

The problem is, when call is made to the bot, after 5 to 10 seconds call is terminated automatically. Whereas he Call status should turn to 'Established' and the call shouldn't end until user does this.Please guide, what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The call is terminating because Teams can't connect to your media endpoint of the InstancePublicIPAddress / InstancePublicPort.  It timesout (i believe in 15 seconds) and terminates the call when it can't get a media connection.

You need to put the IP address of 4.tcp.ngrok.io from your running ngrok settings above into it.
e.g.

```
InstancePublicIPAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("4.tcp.ngrok.io").AddressList[0]
```

You may want to put error checking around the GetHostEntry call in production code.

Comment: Hi Shane, thanks for your reply. We've a CName entry for `4.tcp.ngrok.io`.  Tried passing that to `GetHostEntry` but no success. Moreover, we have an SSL cert issued for our custom domain (that's created against ngrok tcp endpoint).. Any other reasons you could think of?

Comment: You don't need a cert for that.  I assume if your using ngrok, this is just for testing on a dev machine.  Have you tried the IP address instead.  If you lookup 4.tcp.ngrok.io it points to 3.138.180.119.  Try that directly.  This sort of setup is more for development / testing not for production where it's assumed you have port mapping available and not going through ngrok.  You could run wireshark to see that you are getting connection attempts on the internal port (8445) from ngrok.

Comment: I'm also assuming your ServiceFQDN is a name is your ngork https name or a CNAME to that name...  It must be if your getting call event updates.